# Unable to execute multiple query in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am working with Nodejs and i am using expressjs,Right now i am using "insert query" and getting "last inserted id" And tyring to get record from datbase according to "last inserted id" but second query is not working ,Where i am wrong ? Here is my current code

```
static async addServiceDetail(shopId,serviceId,genderTypeId,price,serviceName)
    {
                    const sql2 = `INSERT INTO hc_servicesdetail (shopId, serviceId, genderTypeId,price,serviceName) VALUES (?, ?,  ?, ?, ?)`;
                    const values = [shopId, serviceId, genderTypeId, price, serviceName];
                    //console.log("query is " + sql2);
                    const [datass, _] = await pool.execute(sql2, values);
                    var last_inserted_id=datass.insertId;  // Query working and getting last inserted id
             
                    const sql3 = 'SELECT sd.service_id,sd.gender_type_id,sd.price,s.service_names.time FROM services_detail sd JOIN services s ON sd.service_id=s.id WHERE sd.id = ?';
                    const [rows2, fields2] = await pool.execute(sql3, [last_inserted_id]);
                    console.log(rows2);    // NOT WORKING
    }
```

Comment: What is `pool`, what database are you using?

Comment: What do you mean by "*second query is not working*"? Please be more specific. What error do you get?

Comment: Did you confirm that `last_inserted_id` has the expected value?